# How to integrate AWS secrets into React Application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-hooks, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

We are using Terraform for CI/CD. I need to inject secret for password from AWS Secret Manager. How can we read the values into lambda variable so that I can use in .env property file.

Comment: Used Javascript SDK to access AWS secrete manager.